# can not open tmux session over ssh with `urxvt -e`

Tags: ssh, tmux, urxvt

when I run this command
`urxvt -e ssh -t my-remote-server tmux new -As default-session` in rofi,
urxvt will come out, and exit immeditelly.

the question is: how can I keep urxvt window alive with above situation?

I have tried those, and them all work well.

- `ssh -t my-remote-server tmux new -As default-session` # will attach in the session, unless I detach from the session, this command will not exit.
- `urxvt -e ssh -t my-remote-server tail -f /dev/null`

I tried to use alacritty, it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause: inapproriate TERM env

so the command should be: `ssh -t my-remote-server TERM=xterm-256color tmux new -As default-session`

another thing to know, remote server must have the TERM type (using in the above command) in `/usr/share/terminfo` (usualy in there)